# Relationship Between wind velocity and induced surface water current (general questions)

Tags: fluid-dynamics, atmospheric-science

Consider the following scenario: There is a wind blowing right above lake surface. This wind will induce a surface current in the lake. I am quite new to this topic, so I would be interested to know if there is a well-known model or perhaps some references that gives the relationship between the wind speed and the speed of the surface current. Thank you.

Comment: Here's a related question from the Earth Science site: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/3060/why-is-ocean-surface-velocity-around-3-of-wind-velocity

Answer (score 1):

Current speed at the water surface is approximately related to wind speed by a simple physical relationship. Consider 2D flow in the vertical plane and let the surface stress due to turbulent wind be τw = cdρaU2, where cd is the wind drag coefficient and ρa is the air density. At steady state, τw must be equal to the corresponding stress in water τu = cwρwus2 driving the surface current, where cw is the drag coefficient in water, ρw is the water density and us is the water surface velocity. For a rough estimation let cd ≈ cw, which leads to us = (ρa/ρw)0.5U.  Thus, taking ρa = 1.23 kg m-3 and ρw = 1000 kg m-3 yields us = 0.035U, which indicates that the surface current would be ~3-4% of wind speed. This value rapidly decreases with depth.